# Draw in hidden html5 canvas element doesnt work

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw in a canvas while its parent is `display:none`.
Is there a way to do that?

Here is a jsFiddle to demonstrate my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/kannix/jSj83/

If you just click draw, everything works as expected. If you click Show/Hide and while hidden, click the Draw Button, a click on Show/Hide will reveal the canvas but its still empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You cannot do that.**

The canvas, while technically there, cannot be interacted with in that way. You could, however, instruct the canvas to draw a specific image while it's hidden. Just make sure you don't clear it when showing.

**The user cannot draw while it is hidden though.**

If you just want what is drawn to stay visible after clicking show/hide, remove `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);` from your jQuery.

Comment: damn i've overseen that clear and thought i can't draw in an invisible canvas.. so it seems like my real code has an other problem

Answer (score 8):

You can use the css `visibility` attribute to hide the div rather than using `display`

example:

```
$('#hideBtn').click(function () {
    var hider = $('#hider');
    if(hider.css('visibility') == 'visible') {
        hider.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
    else {
        hider.css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
});
```

Also this line:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Seems to be clearing the drawing.

Answer (score 3):

**A few issues, then it works for you:**

- Don’t clear the canvas in #hideBtn.click
- Use ctx.beginPath() to initialize a path before ctx.arc
- Use jQuery <2.0 when fiddling.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/X7pcm/

```
var ctx = $('#cnv')[0].getContext('2d');

$('#hideBtn').click(function () {
    $('#hider').toggle();        

});

$('#drawBtn').click(function () {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(50, 50, 15, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.fill();
});
```